# Need help troubleshooting a formula to convert article titles to proper case

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of article titles, some of which have proper punctuation and some of which do not. I'm trying to use this formula:

```
=IF(OR(A1="a",A1="of",A1="and",A1="to",A1="for",A1="an",A1="the",A1="nor",A1="but",A1="as",A1="if",A1="or",A1="so",A1="yet",A1="at",A1="by",A1="in",A1="on",A1="per",A1="up",A1="via"),A1,(IF(LOWER(A1)=A1,PROPER(A1),A1)))
```

To capitalize the appropriate words. It's working well, except that it is changing words that are entirely uppercase to words that are only capitalized, e.g. "IIb" to "Iib" and "PF" to "Pf". Can this issue be fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: To skip all-upper words the test condition should be `UPPER(A1)=A1`. But does A1 contain one or several words, and should each word be treated the same?

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches depending on a number of details you have not shared.

### Capitalize the First Letter Only

If your goal is to simply make sure that the words all start with a capital and not impact the rest of the characters in the word, there is no need to test the case.

Take the **1**st character counting from the **LEFT**, and force it to **UPPER**case:

```
    = UPPER(LEFT(A1,1))
```

Get remaining characters starting from the **RIGHT** by subtracting the **1**st character from the **LEN**gth of word:

```
    = RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)
```

Combine the formulas to return the updated (or not) word with the first letter capitalized:

```
    = UPPER(LEFT(A1,1)) & RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)
```

### Use a list to correct capitalization

If there is a lot of customization because of peculiarities in the words (e.g. Acronyms vs Nouns) you might do something similar to your formula however just build a table of acceptable terms then replace your words based on this list.  Maintaining your list outside your formula allows you to update the list without needing to update the formulas, sort it etc.  Because of the default way Excel matches strings (ignores case) and returns strings (matches case) you don't even need pairings just a single column.

**Table Name:**   WordList
**Column Name:** Words

[image: WordList Table]

The formula would then be:

```
    =INDEX(WordList[Words],MATCH(A1,WordList[Words],0),)
```

### Combine both methods

If you wanted to capitalize the first letter of every word except those in your WordList you could combine the formulas in a conditional statement.  Since the Index/Match statement will always error out if there is no match, we can leverage that error using an IFERROR statement that changes the behavior if there is an error:

```
    =IFERROR(INDEX(WordList[Words],MATCH(A1,WordList[Words],0),),
             UPPER(LEFT(A1,1))&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))
```